# Compile problems -- must return a String

Tags: java, string, methods

I am working on a codingbat problem and trying to remove an char from a String and return a string without that char. Below is my code. Please tell me what's wrong with it as I keep getting an error message saying it must return a String.

```
public String missingChar(String str, int n) {
    if (str.length() < n) {
        int idx = str.indexOf(n);
        String a = str.substring(0,idx);
        String b = str.substring(idx+1, str.length());
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Compile problems:

> Error: public String missingChar(String str, int n) {
>                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>       This method must return a result of type String

Comment: If `str.length() >= n`, you don't return anything…

Comment: you need some kind of `else return ...;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers and my comment already mentioned your code is missing a return statement in the else case. But your code logic is also quite flawed:

- do not do `int idx = str.indexOf(n);`
- invert the entire if logic

That will yield:

```
public String missingChar(String str, int n) {
    if (n < str.length()){
        String a = str.substring(0,n);
        String b = str.substring(n+1, str.length());
        return a + b;
    } 
    return str;
}
```

Which results in the output `hllo` for given input `"hello", 1`.

Note that my assumption of the flaws logic results of you trying to compare `n` with the length of the string in the first place: comparing it to the length tells me `n` is supposed to be a index of the string - but then it makes absolutely no sense to call `indexOf` with that `n`. At the same time it could be that `n` is actually the char in the string you want to remove, but then its type should be `char` and you should some error handling in case the character is not found in the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, good point. I reviewed my code and you are absolutely right my code does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return `String` even if the `str.length() < n` condition is not met

```
public String missingChar(String str, int n) {
    if (str.length() < n) {
        int idx = str.indexOf(n);
        String a = str.substring(0,idx);
        String b = str.substring(idx+1, str.length());
        return a + b;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear/simple

your method MUST return a string even if this condition is not met

```
 if (str.length() < n){
```

modify the method in a way that you meet the contract with the return value.

```
public String missingChar(String str, int n) {
  if (str.length() < n){
    int idx = str.indexOf(n);
    String a = str.substring(0,idx);
    String b = str.substring(idx+1, str.length());
    return a + b;
  }else{
       return something;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that all the return paths must return a string, and here you return string only in one of them...

Answer (score -1):

If str.length() >= n, you have no return!